# Pipes in C - replicating the pipe | command

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to replicate the pipe command in bash, by using pipes in c.
For example, the below code snippet should replicate

```
cat from.txt| grep A | head -n 5 | cat | tail -n 1 | wc > to.txt
```

however when I call it with ./pipex from.txt cat "grep A" "head -n 5" "cat" "tail -n 1" "wc" to.txt I get a different result. It seems that the wc is called on the "head -n 5" command and fails to be called on the rest. If I end the statement with 'tail -n 1' the output is correct.

```
int check_errors(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (access(argv[1], R_OK) == -1 || argc != 5)
    {
        if (argc != 5)
        {
            errno = 1;
            perror("Incorrect number of arguments passed to program!!\n");
        }
        if (access(argv[1], R_OK) == -1)
            perror("Error");
        return (1);
    }
    return (0);
}

void    clean_buffer(char **buffer)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((*buffer)[i])
    {
        if ((*buffer)[i] == '\n')
        {
            (*buffer)[i] = '\0';
            break ;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

char    *get_command(char *str)
{
    int     i;
    char    *command;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i])
        i++;
    command = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (i + 1));
    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i])
    {
        command[i] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    command[i] = '\0';
    return (command);
}

static void set_args(char **args, char *cmnd)
{
    args[0] = "/usr/bin/which";
    args[1] = cmnd;
    args[2] = NULL;
}

char    *find_path(char *comm, char **envp, char *buffer)
{
    int     pathpipe[2];
    int     pid;
    char    *args[3];
    char    *cmnd;

    pipe(pathpipe);
    cmnd = get_command(comm);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(pathpipe[1], 1);
        set_args(args, cmnd);
        execve("/usr/bin/which", args, envp);
        perror("");
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        close(pathpipe[1]);
        read(pathpipe[0], buffer, 1024);
        
        clean_buffer(&buffer);
        close(pathpipe[0]);
    }
    free (cmnd);
    return (buffer);
}


static int  ft_splitstrcpy(char **split, char const *s, int slen, int i)
{
    int di;

    di = 0;
    while (di < slen)
    {
        (*split)[di] = s[i];
        di++;
        i++;
    }
    (*split)[di] = '\0';
    return (i);
}

static int  ft_countlen(char const *s, char c)
{
    int i;
    int size;   

    i = 0;
    size = 0;
    while (s[i] != c && s[i] != '\0')
    {
        size++;
        i++;
    }
    return (size);
}

static int  ft_countlines(char const *s, char c)
{
    int     i;
    int     lines;

    i = 0;
    lines = 0;
    while (i < ft_strlen(s))
    {
        while (s[i] == c)
            i++;
        if (s[i] != '\0')
            lines++;
        while (s[i] != c && s[i] != '\0')
            i++;
    }
    return (lines);
}

static void ft_createsplit(char const *s, char c, char **split)
{
    int     i;
    int     l;
    int     lines;

    i = 0;
    l = 0;
    lines = ft_countlines(s, c);
    while (i <= ft_strlen(s) && l <= lines)
    {
        while (s[i] == c)
            i++;
        if (ft_countlen(&s[i], c) == 0)
            break ;
        split[l] = malloc(ft_countlen(&s[i], c) + 1);
        if (split[l] == NULL)
        {
            l++;
            while (l--)
                free(split[l]);
            return ;
        }
        i = ft_splitstrcpy(&split[l], s, ft_countlen(&s[i], c), i);
        i++;
        l++;
    }
}

char    **ft_split(char *s, char *file, char c)
{
    char    **split;
    int     lines;

    if (ft_strlen(s) == 0 || (!s && c == 0))
    {
        split = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
        split[0] = NULL ;
        return (split);
    }
    else
        lines = ft_countlines(s, c);
    split = malloc((sizeof(char *)) * (lines + 2));
    if (split == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    ft_createsplit(s, c, split);
    if (!split)
        return (NULL);
    split[lines] = file;
    split[lines + 1] = NULL;
    return (split);
}

static void first_operation(char **argv, char **envp, int *pipec)
{
    char    buffer[1024];
    char    **argsread;

    find_path(argv[2], envp, buffer);
    argsread = ft_split(argv[2], argv[1], ' ');
    dup2(pipec[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    execve(buffer, argsread, NULL);
    perror("");
}

static void second_operation(char **argv, char **envp, int *pipec, int size)
{
    char    *tempbuffer;
    char    buffer[1024];
    char    **argsread;
    int     tmpfile;
    int     outfile;

    outfile = open(argv[4], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
    find_path(argv[3], envp, buffer);
    dup2(pipec[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(outfile, STDOUT_FILENO);
    argsread = ft_split(argv[3], NULL, ' ');
    execve(buffer, argsread, NULL);
    perror("");
}

int run_pipe( char **argv, char **envp)
{
    int pipec[2];
    int pid;
    int size;

    size = 0;
    if (pipe(pipec) == -1)
        return (4);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
        return (5);
    if (pid == 0)
        first_operation(argv, envp, pipec);
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        close(pipec[1]);
        second_operation(argv, envp, pipec, size);
    }
    return (0);
}

void    execute_command(char *argv, char **envp)
{
    char    buffer[1024];
    char    **argsread;

    find_path(argv, envp, buffer);
    argsread = ft_split(argv, NULL, ' ');
    execve(buffer, argsread, envp);
    perror("");
}

void    execute_final_command(char **argv, char **envp, int argc)
{
    char    buffer[1024];
    char    **argsread;

    find_path(argv[argc - 2], envp, buffer);
    argsread = ft_split(argv[argc - 2], NULL, ' ');
    execve(buffer, argsread, envp);
    perror("");
}

void    do_commands(char **argv, char **envp, int argc, int outfile)
{
    int     pid;
    int     pipes[2];
    int     i;

    i = 2;
    if (pipe(pipes) == -1)
        exit(1);
    while (i++ < argc - 2)
    {
        pid = fork();
        {
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                close(pipes[0]);
                dup2(pipes[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                execute_command(argv[i], envp);
            }
            else
            {
                wait(NULL);
                close(pipes[1]);
                dup2(pipes[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            }
        }
        dup2(outfile, STDOUT_FILENO);
        execute_final_command(argv, envp, argc);
    }
}

void    run_multiple_commands(char **argv, char **envp, int argc, int infile)
{
    int     outfile;
    char    buffer[1024];
    char    **argsread;
    char    *testbuff[1000];

    outfile = open(argv[argc - 1],O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
    dup2(infile, STDIN_FILENO);
    do_commands(argv, envp, argc, outfile);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    int     infile;
    
    // if (check_errors(argc, argv))
    //  return (2);
    infile = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (infile == -1)
        return (3);
    if (argc == 5)
        run_pipe(argv, envp);
    else if (argc > 5)
        run_multiple_commands(argv, envp, argc, infile);
    return (0);
}
```

I seem to be misunderstanding something because I would have thought the lines

```
dup2(outfile, STDOUT_FILENO);
execute_final_command(argv, envp, argc);
```

could be inserted here in run_multiple_commands instead of in do_commands and should work but everything pipes to STDIN from executions in do_command seems to be wiped

```
void    run_multiple_commands(char **argv, char **envp, int argc, int infile)
{
    int     outfile;
    char    buffer[1024];
    char    **argsread;

    outfile = open(argv[argc - 1],O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
    dup2(infile, STDIN_FILENO);
    do_commands(argv, envp, argc, outfile);
        dup2(outfile, STDOUT_FILENO); // this and below line dont work when placed here.
        execute_final_command(argv, envp, argc);

}
```

Basically I want to understand please:

1. Why does this code seem to only partially work when placed in 'do_commands()' and in the while loop. I assume this placement is wrong?
2. Why the (pipes[0], STDIN_FILENO) from do_commands are not being used as the input data for the execute_final_command?
3. Why does my sample command execute wc on the head result in the pipe sequence and not on tail?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry the code needs to be cleaned up to account for argc == 1 and other things. Testbuff i have removed. Im not sure what you meant by 'Why ignore the return of open() and dup2()', if it is in regards to infile, I use it in run_multiple_commands. Args read sets the arguments to be passed to execve. I will edit my original code in the question to include the additional functions. Thanks